# Color of new MS Word hyperlink is black and I want it to be blue

Tags: vba, hyperlink, colors, ms-word, macros

I'm an amateur at vba for Word.
My macro (below) creates a hyperlink from selected text, but the new hyperlink is black, whereas a hyperlink that I create using MS Word's menu, is blue.
I want my macro to create hyperlinks that are blue too.
As you'll see in my macro (below), I've not been able to get the hyperlinks to be blue.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
        Marc
```

Here's the macro:

```
Sub subHyprlinkSrch4PdfFiles_aaa()
'
' subHyprlinkSrch4PdfFiles_aaa Macro
'
'
    Dim strTextToDisplay As String
    Dim rngSelection As RAnge

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=9, Extend:=wdExtend
    Set rngSelection = ActiveDocument.Selection.RAnge

    Application.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    strTextToDisplay = Application.Selection.Text
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.RAnge, Address:="" _
        , SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=strTextToDisplay
    Application.Selection.Style = wdStyleHyperlink
    Application.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    With rngSelection
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    End With


End Sub 'subHyprlinkSrch4PdfFiles_aaa()
```

Here's the sub that I fixed with the solution User Don Jewett gave me yesterday, Nov. 2, 2016 (below):

```
Sub subHyperlinkSelectedTextaaa() 'Hyperlink  to a file whatever text you selected.
    'Hyperlink  to a file whatever text you selected.

    ' http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/type-filedialog.htm

    Dim Sel01 As Selection
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim iFileChosen As Integer
    Dim strFileFullname As String
    Dim Txt2Display As String


    Set Sel01 = Application.Selection

    If Sel01.Type <> wdSelectionIP Then ' i.e., if the selection is valid, i.e., characters are selected
        Txt2Display = Sel01.Text
        'MsgBox Txt2Display
    Else
        MsgBox "No characters were selected validly; so this macro will terminate now."
        Exit Sub
    End If 'If Sel01.Type <> wdSelectionIP Then ' i.e., if the selection is valid, i.e., characters are selected



    ' Open FileDialog "fd" and select a file
    iFileChosen = fd.Show
        If iFileChosen <> -1 Then
            'You didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
            MsgBox "You chose cancel, or something prevented the file-selection-dialog from operating property."
        Else
            strFileFullname = CStr(fd.SelectedItems(1))
            'MsgBox strFileFullname
        End If


    ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388765/color-of-new-ms-word-hyperlink-is-black-and-i-want-it-to-be-blue
    With Application.Selection
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
        'ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Selection.Range, .Text, "", "", .Text
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
           strFileFullname, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Txt2Display
        .Style = wdStyleHyperlink
    End With


End Sub 'subHyperlinkSelectedTextaaa()
```

Comment: That code would not run for me. There is no `ActiveDocument.Selection` property, so it was erroring there to begin with. Also, the `Add` method requires that you have an Address or a SubAddress or both, but not neither. Where do you want the hyperlink to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a hyperlink using the selected text as the link and text, this should work fine:

```
Sub subHyprlinkSrch4PdfFiles_aaa()

    With Application.Selection
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Selection.Range, .Text, "", "", .Text
        .Style = wdStyleHyperlink
    End With

End Sub
```